# When does GC run?

Tags: .net

When does GC actally run? Is it like it runs in a certain interval or when the application demand memory or what?

Comment: There is know way of determining if the GC is about to run, as far as I'm aware. Not easily anyway.

Comment: @Matt: You can register for a full GC notification. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.registerforfullgcnotification.aspx

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: Thanks! I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: When needed.

Longer answer:

- When an allocation cannot be honored
- When an AppDomain is unloaded
- When Windows reports low memory
- When GC.Collect is called

Additionally finalization may run at some point following GC.

Comment: And it is implementation specific, which means even though you know about these rules, you shouldn't build anything around them. It might change in the future. In fact, I think it is highly likely that research into managed memory management isn't done by a longshot yet.

Comment: @Lasse: Good point, so I guess the advice is just to stick to the short answer.

Comment: Yup, I think the corollary to that answer is ", and that's all you need to know."

Answer (score 1):

from [MSFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) (see link for more details):

> The .NET Framework's garbage collector
>   manages the allocation and release of
>   memory for your application. Each time
>   you create a new object, the common
>   language runtime allocates memory for
>   the object from the managed heap. As
>   long as address space is available in
>   the managed heap, the runtime
>   continues to allocate space for new
>   objects. However, memory is not
>   infinite. Eventually the garbage
>   collector must perform a collection in
>   order to free some memory. The garbage
>   collector's optimizing engine
>   determines the best time to perform a
>   collection, based upon the allocations
>   being made. When the garbage collector
>   performs a collection, it checks for
>   objects in the managed heap that are
>   no longer being used by the
>   application and performs the necessary
>   operations to reclaim their memory.operations to reclaim their memory.

Answer (score 0):

1.The .NET Framework's garbage collector manages the
allocation and release of memory for your application.

1. Each time you create an object, the runtime allocates
   memory for the object from the managed heap.
   3.The garbage collector must perform a collection in order
   to free some memory. The garbage collector's optimizing
   engine determines the best time to perform a collection,
   based upon the allocations being made.
   4.When the garbage collector performs a collection, it
   checks for objects in the managed heap that are no longer
   being used by the application and performs the necessary
   operations to reclaim their memory.