# powershell memory space of variable after function return

Tags: powershell, memory-management

This is my powershell function:

```
function A
{
  $a = "securestring"
  return $a
}

$b = A
Remove-Variable -Name b -Scope "Local"
```

$b is no longer in memory by now. But what about $a?

Comment: [AFAIK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIK) also no longer in memory as  runs in the function scope, and is cleared once function has finished running.

Comment: "*$b is no longer in memory by now.*" - how do you know that? The .Net Garbage Collector appears [to be implementation dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785014/when-does-gc-run#comment4009407_3785026) so you have no guarantee when it will run or not. If the word choice `securestring` is a hint that you need to clear physical memory for some important security purpose, it going out of scope of a PowerShell function does not do that.

Comment: Garbage collection and Remove-Variable or Clear-variable is a different  [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782788/powershell-clear-item-variable-vs-remove-variable)  I presume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer: no.  After it exits that scope, its variables are gone.  Also, if you want $B to capture the output of the function, you should really do something like this instead:

```
Function A
{
    "securestring"
}
$B = A
> $B
> securestring
> $B.GetType().Name
> String
Remove-Variable -Name B -Scope 'Local'
> $B
> $B.GetType()
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Your example is a bit convoluted.